# math symbol : bar touching an omega

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, amssymb

In math mode, I would like to create this letter (joint picture)

[image]

(it's a omega with a bar very close to it)

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `\varpi`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok foud it !
$
\varpi
$

should work ...